# schema shared between multiple collections when creating collections in solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Say I've created one collection namely myCollection and indexed some of the documents in it. so after indexing, myCollection's schema changes as per indexing.let's say after indexing following fields are added in configset :

```
a.app_id
b.app_name
c.app_desc
```

till now everything is ok. But whenever i created new collection ex.MyCollection2. Then all of the fields defined above are copied into MyCollection2's schema.xml which i don't want.

I want diff schema.xml for different solr collections.I want fresh collection with only default "ID" field in it.

Is there any way to do this in solrcloud?

Answer (score 1):

[Create a configSet for each collection](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/configsets-api.html#configsets-api) and reference that configuration when creating the collection. The configSet is shared across all collections.

Use the `baseConfigSet` argument to clone an existing configset.

> **baseConfigSet**
>
> The name of the configset to copy as a base. This
>   defaults to `_default`